# Angular CRUD operation without Edit, Delete, Update button (from typescript file, on load of page)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, crud

I have loaded internal JSON data in a table. Now I want to do certain operations on that Angular table:

- Display highest salary employee
- Display employees having salary higher than 70000
- Add text along with salary- for every 2nd index- salary + 'New', for every 5th index - salary + 'Old'
- Update Leena employee salary to be 'To be decided'

`app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

export interface EmployeeData {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  city: string;
  zip: string;
  country: string;
  salary: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  employeeData: EmployeeData[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeData = this.getData();
  }

  getData(): EmployeeData[] {
    return [
      {
        name: 'Leah Carol',
        address: '778 Lorem St.',
        city: 'Witney',
        zip: '45871',
        country: 'Aruba',
        salary: 30149,
      },
     
      {
        name: 'Alexandra Haynes',
        address: 'Ap #514-2705 Curabitur Rd.',
        city: 'Cittanova',
        zip: 'T4S 5M7',
        country: 'Aruba',
        salary: 86821,
      },
      {
        name: 'Carlos Bray',
        address: '117-5777 Magna Street',
        city: 'Gmunden',
        zip: '50141',
        country: 'USA',
        salary: 75030,
      },
      {
        name: 'Perry Tucker',
        address: '4629 Consectetuer St.',
        city: 'Gretna',
        zip: '30178',
        country: 'Netherlands',
        salary: 75179,
      },
      {
        name: 'Jenna Melton',
        address: '156-4435 Mauris Ave',
        city: 'Toronto',
        zip: '09477-202',
        country: 'Aruba',
        salary: 84442,
      },
      {
        name: 'Leena',
        address: 'P.O. Box 263, 7270 Ac St.',
        city: 'Fleurus',
        zip: '37085',
        country: 'USA',
        salary: 66921,
      },
      {
        name: 'Yasir Glass',
        address: 'P.O. Box 346, 2096 Ornare Av.',
        city: 'Lincoln',
        zip: '68125',
        country: 'Canada',
        salary: 62976,
      },
      {
        name: 'Christen Blankenship',
        address: '5457 Pellentesque Ave',
        city: 'Dereham',
        zip: '227613',
        country: 'Aruba',
        salary: 27821,
      },
      {
        name: 'Aubrey Valentine',
        address: 'P.O. Box 125, 8409 Facilisis Av.',
        city: 'Hachy',
        zip: '64229',
        country: 'USA',
        salary: 72260,
      },
      {
        name: 'Serena Goodman',
        address: '355-8060 Mauris Road',
        city: 'Brussegem',
        zip: '36709-953',
        country: 'Taiwan',
        salary: 37644,
      },
      {
        name: 'Mallory Pollard',
        address: 'Ap #825-5389 Arcu. Rd.',
        city: 'Mysore',
        zip: '20-825',
        country: 'Aruba',
        salary: 97266,
      },
      {
        name: 'Sebastian Gamble',
        address: '6858 Justo. Rd.',
        city: 'Minneapolis',
        zip: '3680',
        country: 'Philippines',
        salary: 84711,
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Zip</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let emp of employeeData">
    <td>{{ emp.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.zip }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.country }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.salary }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am getting examples of CRUD operations with button, but I want to get help on doing above operations from ts file and On load.